# What is the purpose of 100 kΩ resistor between gate and source in MOSFETs?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, resistors, mosfet-driver

I've seen many MOSFETs where there's a 100k kΩ resistor between gate and source of the MOSFET.

Can someone tell me what the reason is and how important the value is?

Comment: Could you provide us with an example circuit you came across where there's a 100k resistor between a MOSFET's gate and source?

Comment: It is a pull-down resistor. Its value is not much critical (usually 1k-100k according situation). The purpose to discharge the gate when driving signal disappear. Otherwise the Mosfet can stay in linear region what you do not want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to turn the MOSFET off reliably and reasonably quickly if the connection to the gate should ever go high impedance for any reason (during reset on an MCU GPIO, disconnected connector etc.).

If you have a series resistor from the driver (plus the driver source impedance) you've made a voltage divider, so generally you want the gate pulldown resistor much higher so that it doesn't affect the 'on' gate voltage too much.

The resistor should be low enough that any drain-gate leakage won't cause too much Vgs (so the MOSFET reliably remains off).

That gives quite a bit of range, but something in the range of 10-20kΩ up to a few hundred kΩ is pretty good.

The main reason you don't want to allow the MOSFET to partially turn on (other than turning it on might have some bad effect like starting a motor) is that if the load is heavy and the MOSFET turns *partially* on it can be damaged or destroyed due to heating. The MOSFET dissipates almost no power when 'off' (leakage current x voltage) and usually very little when 'on' (load current squared times Rds(on)), but there is a worst-case condition when the MOSFET resistance equals the load resistance.

For example, supply voltage 12V, load resistance 2Ω, Rds(on) 10mΩ, leakage 1uA.

With MOSFET off, the dissipation is 12uW, utterly negligible.

With MOSFET on, dissipation is about 0.36W, probably no heatsink required.

With MOSFET worst-case partially on (2Ω), current would be 3A and MOSFET dissipation would be 18W.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In your final statement, when the MOSFET is partially ON, how would the current by 3A, instead of 6A?

Comment: 12V across 2Ω (load)  + 2Ω (MOSFET) = 12V/4Ω = 3A. That's the point of maximum MOSFET power dissipation.

Comment: Thank you. So, the 2ohm (MOSFET) is the Resistance value between Gate-Source, is it?

Comment: 2Ω is the MOSFET resistance drain to source resulting from an unknown voltage on the floating gate (it will be a bit more than Vgs(th). The MOSFET gate is like a nF capacitor with some (often tiny) leakage current from the drain (and source) so it can drift around.

Comment: So it is Rds(on) ?

Comment: More like Rds(sort-of-on)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!